# Set UIImagePickerController navigation bar to opaque in iOS 13

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios13

I am presenting a `UIImagePickerController` to pick an image. My code is as simple as:

```
private lazy var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    return picker
}()

func presentPicker() {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen        
    present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am setting `picker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` to have an opaque navigation bar in the picker controller. Unfortunately this doesn't work on iOS 13 and the navigation & status bars are transparent.

**Partial solution**:

```
private func setOpaqueNavigationiOS13() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
}

private func resetNavigationiOS13() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

I call the above functions to make the navigation bar opaque and to reset it when dismissing the picker. This makes the navigation bar opaque but the status bar is transparent. I can implement a hack to make the status bar opaque as well but I guess there should be a simpler solution.

**EDIT**:
I've also tried setting the navigation bar's appearance by the new UINavigationBarAppearance:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Or:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    imagePicker.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    imagePicker.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
    imagePicker.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Anyone that came up with a fix? Thanks

Comment: "This makes the navigation bar opaque but the status bar is transparent" That's correct; you should _never_ set a navigation bar's background color like that. In iOS 13, use the new UIBarAppearance architecture and leave the `isTranslucent` property alone.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my solution in case it's helpful for others.
Although matt's answer is totally correct, it applies when ***all*** of you nav bar setup is done through `UINavigationBarAppearance`. This did not help in my case because I've already done this in AppDelegate:

```
// Make navigation bar transparent throughout whole app
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

And as my app showcases a lot of nav bar styling and I needed a quick fix just to satisfy iOS 13 changes I just did this:

```
// Set nav bar to opaque 
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
}
```

Just don't forget to bring it back to transparent if needed.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 13, the correct way to customize the look of a navigation bar is through the UIBarAppearance architecture (the navigation bar's `standardAppearance` and so forth). You can apply this directly to the navigation bar or use the UINavigationBar appearance proxy.

Comment: I've also tried this approach with no success. I will update my question with the code. Thanks